# What is the real buffer in socket method recv(bufsize) in python and recv(char *buf) in c?

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp

In python, the method is:

```
socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])
```

In C, the method is:

```
int recv( _In_ SOCKET s, _Out_ char *buf, _In_ int len, _In_ int flags)
```

**What is the buffer here in these two method?**

I thought that it was the `receive window size` or `receive buffer` if I create a `TCP` socket. But when I captured the test tcp messages I found I was wrong.

I guess the buffer is the socket buffer. When the tcp messages are coming and first come into `tcp's buffer`(in the transport layer). And then the tcp's receive window begins to slide for receiving data and deliver them to the `socket buffer`(the real buffer in two methods above) if the messages are correct. Finally the data is delivered to app.

Am I right?

Comment: The C *function* corresponds to the Python [`recv_into`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv_into)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Great but what is the difference between recv() and recv_into()? One uses the system buffer and another uses the buffer created by myself?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 types of buffer here:

1. The buffer mentioned in `recv()` is in the user space which is in the running process's memory.
2. The kernel also maintains a buffer in kernel space. When you call `recv()`, the data will be copied from kernel space to user space.